# Listar informações de um banco de dados

Tags: php, html

Tenho uma prototipagem de uma tela que deve listar dados de uma tabela:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho que selecionar a linha inteira da informação, por isso não posso colocar cada dado em uma coluna separada, ou seja, quero por a informação inteira em uma linha mas organizada por colunas, preciso de ajuda. De preferência em php, já que a conexão e o sistema de cadastro é na linguagem.

Comment: Se é só um prototipo pode usar um array com valores fixos para exibir ou exibir os valores fixos direto no html.

Comment: Seria bom saber mais sobre seu problema, como sua estrutura de dados, o que já fez, a estrutura em HTML, se é que já montou. Estamos aqui para tentar ajudar, mas não pra fazer o serviço completo. Se o problema é consultar no banco e pegar o registro inteiro tem um exemplo na resposta desta pergunta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/98598/exibir-produtos-por-categoria-listada-do-banco-de-dados-com-php-pdo