# exibir produtos por categoria listada do banco de dados com PHP PDO

Tags: php, pdo

Estou com dificuldade de fazer a listagem de produtos por categoria, eu criei apenas uma pagina e queria que ficasse dinamico a exibiçao de produtos conforme a categoria listada do banco de dados, mas nao da certo e em `PDO` nao sei como fazer. Então eu criei uma variavel e passei o valor por `GET` e mesmo assim nao funcionou, se alguem puder me ajudar agradeço!!

```
    <p class="titulo-produtos">Produtos..</p>

    <ul class="menu-produtos">
        <?php
            try {
                $categorias = $conexao_pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM categorias ORDER BY nome ASC");
                $executa = $categorias->execute();

                if($executa){
                    while($reg = $categorias->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
                    /* Para recuperar um ARRAY utilize PDO::FETCH_ASSOC */
        ?>

        <li><a href="?categoria=<?php echo $reg->ID;?>"><?php echo $reg->nome?></a></li>

        <?php
                }//if
                    }//while
                else {
                    echo 'Erro ao listar as Categorias!!';
                }
            }//try
            catch(PDOException $e){
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        ?>
    </ul><!-- menu-produtos -->


    <ul class="produtos-internas">
        <?php
            $no = 'categoria';
            try {

                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE categoria = ? AND status = 'on' ORDER BY nome ASC LIMIT 50";
                    if($produtos = $conexao_pdo->prepare($sql)){
                            if($produtos->execute(array($no))){
                                    while($reg = $produtos->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
                                            $dados[] = $reg;       
                                    }              
                            }              
                    }

            } catch(PDOException $e){
                    echo $e->getMessage();
            }

            if(isset($dados)){
                    foreach($dados as $object){
                            ?>
                            <li>
                                    <a href="#">
                                            <span class="rollover"></span>
                                            <img src="admin/uploads/<?php echo $object->foto; ?>" />
                                            <p>
                                                    <?php echo $object->nome ?><br /><br />

                                                    Por <span>R$ <?php echo $object->vlor_avista ?>,00</span> á vista<br />
                                                    ou 12x de R$ <?php echo $object->vlor_aprazo ?>,00 sem juros
                                            </p>
                                    </a>
                            </li>
                            <?php
                    }              
            }

            ?>
    </ul><!-- produtos -->

</section><!-- container -->
```

Comment: Você quer retornar como lista de objetos ou já quer trazer do banco dando `echo`? E como está sua tabela e quais colunas você vai exibir delas?

Comment: eu quero exibilos com echo mesmo estao dentro de uma <li> os parametros que eu quero exibir esta parte ta funcionando so que esta listando todos os produtos cadastrados do banco! eu criei um id e um nome pra tabela categoria e um id, nome e categoria na tabela produtos, queria exibilos tipo categoria 2 exibe os produtos cadastrados na categoria 2 e categoria 3 exibe produtos cadastrados com o id da categoria 3 entende...

Comment: Mateus, clique em [edit] e adicione essas informações na pergunta.

Comment: O que esse try está tratando? Não tem `catch` no seu código.

Comment: `$no` é um número ou um texto?

Comment: Bem lembrado @rray, nem tinha reparado. Essa variavel `$no` é um numero de categoria que vem via GET?

Comment: sim criei uma variavel
$no = $_GET['categoria'];

Comment: Aparece algum erro? `$no` é um número ou string?

Comment: Experimenta estas modificações [aqui](http://pastebin.com/u7CyLRev)

Comment: aparece: Notice: Undefined variable: no
dai eu coloco a variavel aparece esse erro aqui:
Notice: Undefined index: categoria

Comment: okk corrigi o erro da variavel fiz assim: $no = 'categoria';
mas nao esta exibindo nenhum erro e nenhum produto heheh

Comment: Faça o seguinte, como teste crie um _link_ - `print "<a href=\"{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?categoria=1\">Primeira Categoria</a>";` - adiciona-o a essa mesma página, clica sobre ele e vê o que retorna.

Comment: esta voltando para a pagina inicial a index.php
index.php?categoria=1

Comment: Então vai trocando o valor de `$no` manualmente a ver se consegues algum retorno.

Comment: ok vou ir tentando kkk, obg pela ajuda!! :)

Comment: Depois diga o que retornou.

Answer (score 1):

```php
<p class="titulo-produtos">Produtos..</p>
<ul class="menu-produtos">
<?php
    try {
        $sqlCategoria = 'SELECT * FROM categorias ORDER BY nome ASC';
        $resCategoria = $conexao_pdo->prepare($sqlCategoria);
        $resCategoria->execute();
        $categorias = $resCategoria->fetchAll();

        if (count($categorias) === 0 ) { ?>
            echo '<li>Nenhuma categoria cadastrada.</li>';
        } else {
            foreach ($categorias as $categoria) {
                echo '<li><a href="?categoria=' . $categoria['ID'] . '">' .  $categoria['nome'] . '</a></li>';
            }
        }
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
</ul><!-- menu-produtos -->


<ul class="produtos-internas">
<?php
$categoriaId = null;
if (isset($_GET['categoria']) {
    $categoriaId = $_GET['categoria'];
}
try {
    if ($categoriaId === null) {
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE status = "on" ORDER BY nome ASC LIMIT 50';
        $resProdutos = $conexao_pdo->prepare($sql)
        $resProdutos->execute();
        $produtos = $resProdutos->fetchAll();
    } else {
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE categoria = ":categoriaId" AND status = "on" ORDER BY nome ASC LIMIT 50';
        $resProdutos = $conexao_pdo->prepare($sql)
        $resProdutos->execute(array($categoriaId));
        $produtos = $resProdutos->fetchAll();
    }

    if (count($categorias) === 0 ) { ?>
        echo '<li>Nenhuma categoria cadastrada.</li>';
    } else {
        foreach ($produtos as $produto) {
            echo '<li>';
            echo '<a href="#">';
            echo '<span class="rollover"></span>';
            echo '<img src="admin/uploads/' . $produto['foto'] . '" />';
            echo '<p>' . $produto['nome'] . '</p>;
            echo '</a>';
            echo '</li>';
        }
    }
} catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
</ul><!-- produtos -->
```